# Sending SMS through iPad Air's iMessages

Tags: ipad, messages, sms

How do I send text messages to non apple devices with my iPad Air with cellular? I have the iMessage worked out but can't figure out SMS.

Answer (score 2):

**SMS's** can only be sent through an iPhone, as it requires a carrier's plan and a phone number associated to it, which iPad's lacks of.

As stated by [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3529):

> **Which Apple products support Messages using SMS and MMS?**
>
> To use Messages with SMS and MMS, you **need an iPhone**.